# database no record after INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have the folowing ishue i am trying to save picture in my database with folowing code

```
    <?php

    $cn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'xkmpfg3t', 'test');

    foreach (glob('*.jpg') as $img) {
        $picName = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, "$img");
        $picData = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, file_get_contents("$img"));
        if (mysqli_ping($cn)) {
            printf("Our connection is ok!\n");
            mysqli_query($cn, "INSERT INTO `pictures` (`user_id`,`picture_id`,`picture_name`,`picture`) VALUES ('1','','$picName','$picData')");
        } else {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($cn));
        }
    }
?>
```

Everything work just fine while i put  image larger than 1MB, after i send request i do not get any error but when i look at the table there is no record of the image. I use xampp and i modify my.ini file to look like this:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

is there any problem in my code or something? Sorry for the english.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements, check for Errors after executing SQL Statements (mysqli_error()).

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but how about just not storing file data in a database?

Comment: Do you have the auto commit enabled?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: there is not mistakes after the querys i did it with Prepared statement and the result is the same the files under 1MB are recorded but the large files (over 1MB) are not the only diference now is that i recive there names and they are recorded in DB but the content is missing. i think i have to change something in these configuration files but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

I found it first i made parameterized queries like that:

```
<?php

$cn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'xkmpfg3t', 'test');
foreach (glob('*.jpg') as $img) {
    $picName = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, "$img");
    $picData = file_get_contents($img);
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, "INSERT INTO pictures (`user_id`,`picture_id`,`picture_name`,`picture`) VALUES ('1',NULL,?,?)")or die(mysqli_errno($cn));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $picName, file_get_contents($img)) or die(mysqli_errno($cn));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_errno($cn));
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

but it dos not help. It turns out that i have to change `innodb_log_file_size` to a greater than default value which is 5M, because it alows me to send pacets which are 10% of that value for some reason. I change it to 50M and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check parameters in your php.ini file. Amounts is just example.

```
memory_limit=128M
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=50M
```

Comment: i found it. It was not in my php.ini it was in my.ini file the database did not alow me to save the info and i changed `innodb_log_file_size = 50` and everything is running.